# How can we delete item permanently without storing in Recycle Bin?

Tags: sitecore-client

By default if we delete item, it stores into `Recycle Bin`. This is desire and essential behavior.

[image]

But if we want delete item permanently, can we do using any `config` change?

Please suggest any approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is `RecycleBinActive` setting.

Change it to `false` and it should do the trick.

Just create a patch file `Disable.Recycle.Bin.config` and add it to `App_Config/Include` folder:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="RecycleBinActive">
        <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 9):

We can do this using [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx).

If don't want to store item into `Recycling Bin`, need to pass `Permanently` parameter.  This is very fast and easy way which is recommended for bulk items deletion.

## Below is sample example:

```
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {
  Get-Item "master:/content/Something" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Permanently
}
```

If you're working with a `large volume` of data. In those cases you might also want to introduce the `Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext` technique, which will improve ***performance*** by avoiding event etc.

**Note:** Because this does disable events etc. You will probably need to re-index and run a smart publish once the items are deleted.

Please go through link https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items.html for more details .

[image]

If we passing `Permanently` - Specifies the item should be deleted rather than recycled.

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to do it occasionally, you can use the good old [DB Browser](http://dinbror.dk/blog/sitecore-admin-pages-cheat-sheet/#dbbrowser) at `https://your-sitecore/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx`.

[image: The database browser]

Answer (score 0):

To do this manually on an occasional basis hold the shift key while pressing the delete key or choosing "Delete" of the context menu.